# Spring data query to fetch based on nested object and principal

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

I have Order entity which has a `many-to-one` relationship with `Customer` entity. I want to write a Spring Data JPA query to fetch all the orders that belong to the `customer id`.

Below is my `Order` entity

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = "customer")
@ToString(exclude = "customer")
@Entity
@Table(name = "orders")
public class Order {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    

private double price;
private LocalDate date;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="customer_id", nullable = false)
    @JsonBackReference
    private Customer customer;
    ...
```

Spring Data JPA

```
@Repository
public interface OrderRepository extends JpaRepository<Order, Long> {

    @Query("select  orders from Order  where orders.customer.id = ?#{principal.id}")
    Page<Order> findAll(Pageable pageable);
}
```

Where am I going wrong? Also can we write the above query using fluent-style based on the method naming convention in Spring Data JPA.

Comment: Can you add the Customer entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This HQL query should work:

```
@Query("select o from Order o inner join o.customer c where c.id = ?#{principal.id}")
```

The query based on the method name doesn't seem to support join operations, or at least I couldn't find the keyword. You can check the documentation for the [list of supported keywords](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation).